# How to map simple auth requirements onto AspNetCore authn/authz concepts

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization

I am working on upgrading a legacy ASP.NET application to ASP.NET Core.

Our application has (to me) fairly basic authentication and authorization requirements:

- We need to run specific logic to authenticate a request (calls into a central authentication service)
- We want all actions to reject unauthenticated requests by default
- We want the ability to allow anonymous requests with allow anonymous
- Users can be members of a few different roles and we want the ability to accept/reject requests based on those. One of the roles is required by default, (which can be opted out of for specific endpoints) while the others are opt-in.
- When a request is rejected, we want to customize what happens (e. g. we may send 403 or may redirect the user to a specific page)

I am trying to figure out how best to leverage the many, many Authorization and Authentication interfaces and classes in Asp.NET Core to implement our flow, but after reading the MSFT docs I'm still coming away feeling like I'm missing something.

For example, I've been able to get things working using a custom middleware component to perform authentication and set identity and a custom authorize filter to handle the authorization, but I find myself needing to do things like check for `AllowAnonymous` manually which doesn't feel right.

Can anyone map the above requirements to the relevant ASP.NET Core pieces?

Comment: How is that currently done in ASP.NET?

Comment: Where do your users come from? Are you using Identity? An external authentication provider? Your requirements can be implemented easily using authorization policies and authorization filters. Creating a custom middleware is almost always the wrong thing to do with auth topics in ASP.NET Core 2.x.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto in old ASP.NET, I have an HttpModule (to be common across the Mvc and WebApi stacks) which sets up Thread.CurrentPrincipal and HttpContext.User at the beginning of each request using our custom authn logic. We then have a custom implementation of IAuthorizationFilter which plugs in the accept/reject and role check logic. I'm hoping that with ASP.NET Core's richer model we can push more onto the base framework.

Comment: @poke based on information in the request, we can authenticate the user by calling off to another internal service. It's not some standard provider. Today (ASP.NET) we use the information we get back to set up Thread/HttpContext identity, so I'm hoping we can keep doing that. I'm glad to hear that you see a path to implementing this easily without restoring to custom middleware, as that's exactly what I'm looking for. At this point I'm not sure where to place the custom logic (e. g. policies, an IPolicyEvaluator, a custom AuthorizeFilter, etc. ).

Comment: if you have some custom authentication mechanism, I would start with building your own authentication scheme so that you can authenticate the users properly with all the information necessary. Once you have that, you can just use an authorization filter to implement most of your security checks.

Comment: @poke thanks! It sounds like you are suggesting that I follow a pattern like this one: https://joonasw.net/view/creating-auth-scheme-in-aspnet-core-2. I'm still not completely sure how to map my role restrictions to policies, especially where by default I want to require role X but I want specific controller actions to be able to require no roles or both role X and role Y. Thoughts?

Comment: You just create multiple policies that reflect your different set of authorization requirements. Using the [`AuthorizationPolicyBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationpolicybuilder) you can create a policy and easily [require roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationpolicybuilder.requirerole?view=aspnetcore-2.2) as necessary.

Comment: @poke what I'm running into is that when I set a default policy, it is always ANDed with any policy applied at the controller level. I want to require role X by default, but also to be able to opt out of this behavior.

Comment: Do you have a `AuthorizeFilter` registered as a global filter that enforces the default policy? Otherwise, an autorize attribute with an explicit policy shouldn’t enforce the default policy. – You could build some opt-out behavior using custom authorization filters but it’s a lot easier to just not use a global filter and instead use `[Authorize]` on controller-level to enable authorization on a larger scale, while not doing that if you need to opt-out somewhere. That might require a bit duplication but ultimately is the simplest solution here.